# Umbraco multiple sites same node name throws 404

Tags: umbraco

I have an umbraco installation that has two sites in it both with a page called `Contact Us` in the root.  I have configured their domain names so in development I have `site1.local` and `site2.local`

if I go to `site1.local/contact-us/` the page works fine but then if I try to go to second sites contact us page (`site2.local/contact-us/`) it just redirects me to the first sites 404 page.

Has anyone come across this problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have set up a template and assigned it to the page as you get redirected to the main 404 if no template is set.  If so

Comment: d'oh! had set up the template but not assigned it